# How to plot a particular solution in the form f(x,y)=0 on Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, implicit

I need to plot a two variable function on Gnuplot when it intersects with 0, that is: f(x,y)=0. It will mean a 2D plot rather than 3D.
My attempt up to now is:

```
set term cairolatex eps standalone size 6in,6in lw 7
set key box opaque samplen 6
set key spacing 1.5
set key Right
set key height 2
set key width 3
f(x,y)=...
set output 'V.tex'
plot f(x,y)=0 title '\small${\hat{V}=2}$' lc rgb "black"
set out
```

but it returns *function to plot expected*.

Just in case, the *workaround* given in 5.2 section of the Gnuplot FAQ in `http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html` does not produce a .tex file that I can compile.

Comment: It depends on the function. Can you solve 0=f(x,y)=... explicitly (i.e. analytically) for y? If yes, then plotting y(x) will be your solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot isolate y in f(x,y).

Comment: @gibarian Can you please give a (simplified) example of one of your functions `f(x,y)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to combine the code from the FAQ (@gdupras's answer) with the code you showed at first.

```
set term cairolatex eps standalone size 6in,6in lw 7
set key box opaque samplen 6
set key spacing 1.5
set key Right
set key height 2
set key width 3

f(x,y) = y - x**2 / tan(y)  
set contour base  
set cntrparam levels discrete 0.0  
unset surface  
set table $TEMP  
splot f(x,y)  
unset table  

set output 'V.tex'
plot $TEMP w l title '\small${\hat{V}=2}$' lc rgb "black"
set out
```

In my environment, this code generates "V.tex" and I get the following figure (PDF converted to PNG) after compiling.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the gnuplot FAQ: http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html

From that page:

> **5.2 Implicit defined graphs**
>
> Implicit graphs or curves cannot be plotted directly in gnuplot . However there is a workaround.
>
> ```
> gnuplot> # An example. Place your definition in the following line:  
> gnuplot> f(x,y) = y - x**2 / tan(y)  
> gnuplot> set contour base  
> gnuplot> set cntrparam levels discrete 0.0  
> gnuplot> unset surface  
> gnuplot> set table $TEMP  
> gnuplot> splot f(x,y)  
> gnuplot> unset table  
> gnuplot> plot $TEMP w l
> ```
>
> The trick is to draw the single contour line `z=0` of the surface `z=f(x,y)`, and store the resulting contour curve to a temporary file or datablock.

Comment: I simultaneously edit my question adding that this is not compiling...